# Is it possible to have two different charts on one graph?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to have a `LineChart` and a `BarChart` on the same graph, both with MarkerViews.

I can get them to draw on the same chart just by adding a `LineChart` on top of a view with a `BarChart` However, the `LineChart` markerview overrides the bar chart's markerview.

Is this a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, that is possible using a `CombinedChart`.

You can find an example on how to create such a chart here: [CombinedChart example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java)

Basically you will have to create a `LineData` and `BarData` object and set them for your `CombinedData` object which is then set for the chart.

Comment: While using CombinedChart with a BarChart with multiple datasets, there are issues with the sizing of the charts.